# How do I create a loop in python that will break once user inputs quit?

Tags: python

[image]

I've edited my code to the following:

```
while(True):
    #get user to input a noun as a string variable
    noun = input()
    
    #get user to input a positive number for the integer variable
    number = int(input())

    #if the user inputs quit into the string variable stop program
    if noun == 'quit':
        break
    #otherwise print the output
    else:
        print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(number,noun))
```

And I get the following error codes:
[image]

Comment: Put the input statements in the while loop, or it will only ask once.

Comment: The `else` only executes if the `while` condition is not true, you remove the `else` and it will execute every time, unless you break before it (which is what you want)

Comment: Also indent properly.  the `else` should align with the `if`.  It's currently associated with the `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you edited the code since these answers, this should work

```
while(True):
    noun, number = input().split()
    number = int(number)

    #if the user inputs quit into the string variable stop program
    if noun == 'quit':
        break
    #otherwise print the output
    else:
        print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(number,noun))
```

Your problem was that you're calling input twice every loop. So, noun was set to `'apples 5'` and number was set to `'shoes 2'` which cannot be converted to an integer. You can split the input to get your noun and number.

Comment: I love you so much right now. lol Splitting the input finally made it work in order to pass all  the tests in my program.

Answer (score 1):

You should be taking the input inside the loop, otherwise it is an endless loop or if you did write quit then it would just run once. Also there is no need for the == 0 condition to break from the loop according to the problem you have presented.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you just take the first input, just get the inputs inside the loop insted.

Also the else should be idented with the if statement and you don't need the number == 0 condition, so the resulting code should be somehting like:

```
while(True):
    #get user to input a noun as a string variable
    noun = input()
    
    #get user to input a positive number for the integer variable
    number = int(input())

    if noun == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(number,noun))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would write. :)

```
while True:
    noun = input("Enter a noun: ")
    if noun == 'quit':
        print("Quitting the program...")
        break

    while True:
        number = input("Enter a number: ")
        try:
           if type(int(number)) == int:
               break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")
 
    if number == '0':
        print("Quitting the program...")
        break
    
    print("Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.".format(number, noun))
```